# QtGui.QFileDialog Unicode designations?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qfiledialog

This is making me crazy and I have searched all over and can't find anyone who is having this problem.  I can't really describe it well in a search to look for an answer so I am coming to you.

This is my code:

```
def browse(self):

    directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName (self, "Find Files")

    if directory:
        self.newfilepath.setText(str(directory))
    else:
        self.newfilepath.setText('No file selected')
```

I am trying to put the result into a field in a window that I would then push to a sqlite db for later retrieval.  Unfortunately the following code gives me a result I don't seem to be able to fix.

```
    name1 = (self.newdescript.toPlainText())
```

The result is:

```
(u'F:/GeoDatabase/GeoDatabase2.py', u'All Files (*.*)')
```

What I want is just:

```
F:/GeoDatabase/GeoDatabase2.py
```

or maybe:

```
'F:/GeoDatabase/GeoDatabase2.py'
```

How do I get it to give me just the path name and not all the other crap. Nothing I do seems to make a difference and I don't know where else to turn.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please show a *minimal* example *that we can run* that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Bakuriu. I don't understand your complaint: the question seems clear enough, and the provided code and output is perfectly sufficient to diagnose the problem. The tags could have been better, though.

Comment: @ekhumoro No it wasn't. As I said in my comment I wrote a small code containing those lines I didn't have any problem. The OP failed in describing its situation. If he had posted a complete example it would have been clear that the error was due to using PySide instead of PyQt even without providing the tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a little difference between PyQt4 and PySide.

With PyQt4, all of the static `QFileDialog` methods (such as `getOpenFileName`) either return a single string or (for `getOpenFileNames`) a list of strings.

But with PySide, `getExistingDirectory` returns a single string, but all the other methods return a tuple consisting of a string/list of strings, plus the selected filter.

To work around this, in PySide, your code would need to look like this:

```
def browse(self):
    path, filter = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Find Files")
    if path:
        self.newfilepath.setText(path)
    else:
        self.newfilepath.setText('No file selected')
```

**PS**:

Strictly speaking, PySide is more correct here. The C++ API modifies one of its arguments to supply the selected filter, so returning a tuple is the most pythonic way to represent that.

PyQt4 fails to honour the modified argument, but is perhaps more intuitive as a result of that.

**PPS**:

For PyQt5, there is no longer any difference with PySide as it now also returns a tuple of path(s) and filter.

Comment: +1. Just a note: in PyQt5, the mentioned methods also return a tuple of result and filter, matching the C++ API. So this difference only applies to PyQt4.

Comment: @mata. Thanks - I suspected that might be the case, but didn't get around to testing it. I've now updated my answer with your correction.